# Xcode workspace with iOS and macOS

Tags: xcode8

I have an iOS app which I need to build a supporting app for macOS. I was hoping to share code between them, specially the DataModel.

As the iOS app was using Pods, there was already a workspace.

I pulled in the macOS project into the workspace, and I can see all its files with no problem. But I don't seem to be able to figure out how to 'use' the class files from the iOS project in the macOS project. Would it have anything to do with Modules?

Or should I just make a new Target that is a macOS application?

I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 at the moment, and the projects are in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the source files you want to use and tick the "Target Membership" for your macOS target in the Inspector:

[image]

---

Update:

To use common code in different projects, make an extra project for your common code which builds as a Framework and include this framework in the iOS and in the macOS.

[This tutorial](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/creating-your-first-ios-framework) might be helpful.

Comment: So don't add the macOS project and just make a new Target in the iOS project?

Comment: Misunderstood than. Sorry. Updated answer.